# Retrieve the value of the SUM function at each round of while loop PHP SQL

Tags: php, sql

this is the first time I ask a question on a forum so excuse me in advance if you have difficult to understand my request.

```
 $somm = 'SELECT SUM(lenght- start) FROM gantt WHERE ' . $id['idValeur'] < 2 . '';
```

I get `$id['idValue']` at each round of while loop and I would like that at each round of loop I can have access to the result of `SUM(length - start)` for example, for an id of 2, I want to have in response `(length1 - start1 + length2 - stat2) = result`

First of all, is it possible?
If so, what should I go for.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Most things are possible, if you work at it. If the result generates multiple rows then you can loop through them, yes. I would advise giving your calculated columns an alias so they're easy to reference in the PHP code. Then you can fetch the results using any of the normal methods in PDO or mysqli or whatever, as are well documented and covered in many many tutorials already. It's not clear what you've tried or where you're stuck exactly?

Comment: So, I think it's good, I put an alias to my table and the rest of the code came straight to my mind. Thank you for making me think about putting this one on, I'm not sure I would have clicked otherwise...